# How do I convert existing AWS DynamoDB Locals Tables into Global Tables using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have two DynamoDB tables in two different regions, with the same name, both stream enabled, both showing Global Table version 2019.11.21, one has data and one is empty. If I give example, they can be shown like below:

- Region: us-east-1
- Table name: MyTable
- Global Table Version: 2019.11.21
- Table has items: Yes

- Region: us-east-2
- Table name: MyTable
- Global Table Version: 2019.11.21
- Table has items: No

I used `boto3` DynamoDB `client.create_global_table()` and `client.update_global_table()` without any success.

#1. Trying to create Global Table

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
response = client.create_global_table(
    GlobalTableName='MyTable',
    ReplicationGroup=[
        {
            'RegionName': 'us-east-1'
        },
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateGlobalTable operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Tables must be empty. These tables contain items: [TableReplica{regionName=us-east-1, tableName=MyTable}]
```

I understand that `client.create_global_table()` API call only applies to DynamoDB Table version `2017.11.29` which requires the tables to be empty. So, this won't work for me. [Ref: here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html?highlight=dynamodb#DynamoDB.Client.create_global_table)

#2. Trying to update Global Table

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
update_response = client.update_global_table(
    GlobalTableName='MyTable',
    ReplicaUpdates=[
        {
            'Create': {
                'RegionName': 'us-east-1'
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
botocore.errorfactory.GlobalTableNotFoundException: An error occurred (GlobalTableNotFoundException) when calling the UpdateGlobalTable operation: Global table not found: Global table with name: 'Mytable' does not exist.
```

Adding second region `us-east-2` also do not help.

The boto3 documentation version 1.17.66 does not specify anything particular about the DynamoDB table version in which this operation applies to. So, I believe this should work for version 2019.11.21, but the Global Table first has to be in place. [Ref: here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html?highlight=dynamodb#DynamoDB.Client.update_global_table)

According to [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-convert-your-single-region-amazon-dynamodb-tables-to-global-tables/), a single region existing Local Table with items can be converted to a Global table. The example used in the blog post was using AWS CLI, but mentioned that AWS SDKs also could be used.

So, what how can I do this with boto3?

Comment: So your `MyTable` is the newer version or the old version?

Comment: Newer version `2019.11.21`.

Comment: So have you used [update_table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_table)? This is different function to what you shown in the question. So its getting a bit confusing.

Comment: No, I used `update_global_table`, not `update_table`.

Comment: You should be using update_table. Can you try with that?

Comment: No, @Marcin, that won't help. `update_table` is not for converting a local table into a global table. In fact, `update_global_table` is not either. It is to add or remove a region for a global table which has to be converted to a global table first.

Comment: The AWS blog that you referenced uses update table for this. So I'm not sure what is different in your case?

Comment: Uhha! It has  `{ 'Create': {...}, 'Update': {...}, 'Delete': {...} }` with region. I will give a shot.

Comment: I meant, It has  `ReplicaUpdates=[ { 'Create': {...}, 'Update': {...}, 'Delete': {...} } ]` with region.

Comment: How did it go? I think this is the right function to use.

Comment: Could not make it yet. Not sure what properties are required and what are optional. Trying to figure out.

Comment: No luck. I get `Replica modification must be the only operation in the request` if I use other properties like `BillingMode`, `ProvisionedThroughput`. If I do not provide them, I get `Table write capacity should either be Pay-Per-Request or AutoScaled`.

Comment: Your table must be autoscaled. So update it first to be autoscaled, and then update it again for global table.

Comment: Autoscaled or PAY_PER_REQUEST. I used PAY_PER_REQUEST. It worked. Thanks so much @Marcin!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you don't mind I will provide an answer:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

To update the existing local dynamodb table to global table, two steps need to be executed, both can be done using [update_table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_table):

1. The existing table must be set to `PAY_PER_REQUEST` mode or `AutoScale` using `update_table`.
2. Once the table is in one of these mode, `update_table` can be used again to set the table to global mode as explained in [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-convert-your-single-region-amazon-dynamodb-tables-to-global-tables/).